# Problem with using nonnegative Lagrange Multiplier

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have read in several places that the sign of the Lagrange Multiplier is unimportant for finding the critical points of the Lagrangian. However, I don't believe that this is entirely true. In my professor's lecture, we were presented with the following setup:

Maximize $f(x)$ subject to the constraint $g(x)\geq0$, where the Lagrangian is expressed as $L(x, \lambda)=f(x)+\lambda g(x)$, $\lambda g(x)\geq0$, and $\lambda\geq0$.

Supposing for simplicity that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are each both concave and differentiable, then the value $x_0$ solves the max problem iff $x_0$ satisfies the first-order condition of the Lagrangian. However, to solve the first-order condition of the Lagrangian, it would have to be true that $-f'(x_0)=\lambda g'(x_0)$. But $\lambda$ is non-negative! Is it then true that $f'(x_0)$ and $g'(x_0)$ cannot have the same sign?

Comment: The sign of Lagrange multipliers indeed plays no role for the usual constraint $g (x)=0$. But in your case the constraint is $g (x)\ge0$.

Comment: So did my professor misrepresent the Lagrangian for an inequality constraint?

Comment: We don't know exactly what your professor said or whether you misheard or misunderstood it.  It's a simple fact that the sign of the Lagrange multiplier does matter for inequality constraints.

Comment: So in this case, either the lambdas should be non-positive, or the second term of the Lagrangian should be subtracted? @BrianBorchers

Comment: I don't understand your question.  The statements that you've quoted from your professor are correct.  You seem to have misunderstood the point that for an inequality constraint, we require the Lagrange multiplier to be nonnegative.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I very clearly state that the Lagrangian multipliers are nonnegative, but thank you for the help anyways.

Comment: You say that "I have read in several places that the sign of the Lagrange Multiplier is unimportant for finding the critical points of the Lagrangian."  Presumably, those authors were referring to problems with equality constraints rather than inequality constraints.

Comment: @BrianBorchers yes you are correct about this, but I’m confused about the way my professor presented the Lagrangian for inequality constraints. If the Lagrangian multipliers are nonnegative and the second term of the Lagrangian is added rather than subtracted, how could a solution exist when the derivatives of f and g have the same sign?

Comment: If $g(x_{0})\geq 0$ and $f'(x_{0})$ and $g'(x_{0})$ are both positive, then $x_{0}$ can't be a maximum of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x) \geq 0$.  It could be a minimum.  To see this, consider that for a small $\delta$, $f(x_{0}+\delta)>f(x_{0})$ and $g(x_{0}+\delta)>g(x_{0})\geq 0$.

Comment: The answer to the last question on your professor's slide is "Yes- if $f'(x_{0})$ and $g'(x_{0})$ have the same sign then $x_{0}$ cannot be a maximum point."  (The case where both derivatives are negative is a straight forward variant.)

Comment: @BrianBorchers I understand now, thank you.